Emulator process has terminated with error: "qemu-system-x86_64.exe- Entry Point Not Found
I am trying to run emulator on Windows 10 machine. but it's terminating with with error pop-up.
Error Message: The procedure for entry point SystemParametersInfoForDpi could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local|Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\ Qt6GuiAndroidEmu.dll
Android Studio Version: Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 3

Check troubleshooting page ; verify free disk space of > 5GB.

This question is similar to: Emulator in Android Studio doesn't start. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
